# loop, function, conditional statements (etc.) to look at 3 columns to determine accuracy (e.g., x = correct if colA=1, colB=1, & colC=2

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement, dplyr

I struggle immensely with writing loops and functions. I have successfully avoided them by relying on if_else() and ifelse, the structure of which makes sense to me. Until now.

I am working with cognitive task data. Each trial asks participants to provide a response for three variables; variableA, variableB, variableC. My df has a column for each variable per trial. To determine correctness I need to see if variableA == 1, variableB == 1, AND variableC == 2. Some of the trials have different 'correct answers' but for simplicity's sake, the 'correct answer' for the 'Set' trials is A=1,B=1,C=2.

I'm able to filter the rows by 'Set' and "Test', but I'm struggling to write something that basically does "if A == 1, B == 1, & C == 2 then Y" (or 1, True, or some other way of just indicating accuracy).

```
DF <- data.frame(QType = c("Set","Set","Set","Set","Set","Test"), 
                 varA = c("1","1","2","1","1","2"),
                 varB = c("1","1","1","0","1","0"), 
                 varC = c("2","1","2","2","2","2"), 
                 correct = "")
```

```
DF$correct <- DF %>%
  filter(QType == "Set") %>%
  if_else(c(varA == 1 & varB == 1 & varC == 2), 1, 0)

SetCorrect <- c(DF$varA == 1 & DF$varB == 1 & DF$varC == 2) 
DF$correct <- DF %>%
  filter(QType == "Set") %>%
  if_else(SetCorrect, 1, 0)

DF %>%
  filter(QType == "Set") %>%
  mutate(correct = case_when(varA == "1" ~ "1",
                             varB == "1" ~ "1",
                             varC == "1" ~ "1"))
```

Comment: `with(DF[DF$QType == "Set", ], ifelse(varA == "1" & varB == "1" & varC == "2", TRUE, FALSE))`? Or in `dplyr`-syntax: `DF %>% filter(QType == "Set") %>% mutate(correct = if_else(varA == "1" & varB == "1" & varC == "2", TRUE, FALSE))` or `DF %>% filter(QType == "Set") %>% mutate(correct = case_when(varA == "1" &  varB == "1" & varC == "2" ~ TRUE, .default = FALSE))` (for two cases, `if_else` is enough)

Comment: @Friede, this should probably be an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @hwright A generalizable solution might be to create a second data.frame serving as a "key" of correct answers (for "set", "test", and perhaps others), and then "joining" to your data by columns `QType`, `varA`, `varB`, and `varC`.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want? (I can't quite figure out what you want to do when `QType` is "Test" ...)

```r
DF <- DF %>%
  filter(QType == "Set") %>%
  mutate(correct = (varA == 1 & varB == 1 & varC == 2))
```